# Apprise is a great plugin, but with a little problem. What to change?

Tags: jquery, message, alert

Here is this great plugin: http://thrivingkings.com/apprise/

When I use `apprise('Hello');` or other function it doesn't stop, it continues to execute jQuery code while simple `alert("hello");` would stop executing js code. So, any ideas how to solve this?

I really want to use it, because it is extremely cool and light-weighted. (Or maybe you know any other plugins for alert messages as awesome as this one?).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's *meant* to be non-blocking. In other words, if you want your subsequent code to wait until the `apprise` box has closed, you'll have to pass in a continuation:

`apprise('Hello', null, function() { /* continuation */ });`

**Edit:**

Further clarification:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    apprise('Hello', null, function(){
        // the code here will execute after the msg box has been closed
    });
    // this code will execute immediately, not waiting for the box to close
});
```

This is as designed in a non-blocking call. *Any* code that you want to have execute after the box has been close *must* be contained in the continuation.

Comment: +1, but the problem still exists, because the code after `{ /* continuation */ });` still is being executed. What do you think, is it bad practise to make a big delay, smth like `delay(123456789)`?